# Wordpress, result array of 'post_name'

Tags: array, slug

when I try to run this array it doesn't give me the exact results of the 4 slugs I want to get, but many more results come out.

```
$slugArray = array(

    'post_type' =>  'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'post_name__in' => array( 'permalink1', 'permalink2', 'permalink3', 'permalink4' ),

);



 // Get all posts
$query = new WP_Query($slugArray);

$posts = $query->get_posts();


foreach ($posts as $post) {


    if($post) {


                    
    //if $post->post_name, (preg_match("/^([0-9]+)\-(.*)/", $match))
        if(preg_match("/^([0-9]+)\-(.*)/", $post->post_name, $match))
    $new_slug = (intval($match[1])+1) . "-" . $match[2];
        else
            $new_slug = "1-" . $post->post_name;

    // Prepare arguments
    $args = array(
        'ID' => $post->ID,          
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_name' => $new_slug,
    );
    // Update post
    //wp_update_post( $args );
        var_dump ($args);
}
}

?>
```

so i should just get:

```
array(3) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["post_name__in"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(20) "permalink1" [1]=> string(30) "permalink2" [2]=> string(12) "permalink3" [3]=> string(22) "permalink4" }
```

but instead I get another 1000 different post_name results.

if i try to put this it comes out only one slug, but the problem is that i need an array with multiple slugs:

```
'name' => 'permalink1',
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps show the whole function rather than parts of it, so that people can get a better idea how to help.

Comment: You are dumping `$args`, but waiting for the `$slugArray` dump. Also, `posts_per_page` is not an argument of `wp_update_post()`. Finally, getting 1000 posts means that your query returns 1000 posts. You should rethink your code before asking the question.

Comment: ok I'm not very professional in code yet, but so what's the solution? can you help me or is it just an answer saying i was wrong?